# Trying to add div classes however it is not working with my Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use some JavaScript to allow for a user to click through a number of divs. I have uploaded the code to JSFiddle and you can view it here: http://jsfiddle.net/WjRK2/64/

I believe the problem that I am running into is trying to switch the classes of the divs so that they work properly with the JavaScript:

```
$('#menu a').click(function (e) {
    $('#content div.level1').removeClass('makeVisible');
    divToMakeVisible = $(this).attr('href');
    $(divToMakeVisible).addClass('makeVisible');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Any help is welcome because I feel like I am stuck in a rut and I am unable to figure out how to get out of it.

Comment: Have a look at the console and fix the error which should be listed (at least if the Javascript you've posted is wrapped in an `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` or is placed right before the closing `<body />`.

Comment: `divToMakeVisible` is string... how can you add a class to string?

Comment: @FlashThunder That string has been placed within a jQuery selector, making something like `$('#div2')`. @OP Lesson number one when testing jQuery on jsfiddle: Include jQuery into your jsfiddle.

Comment: @oGeez yeah but using href for that seems to be a bit invalid. `rel` ? What will mr. Google say?

Comment: @FlashThunder Oh I wasn't saying that `href` is best to use there (perhaps a `data-*`). I'm just saying, it'll work.

Comment: @oGeez true, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks for the minimal/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demo.

That sarcasm aside, the problems with your code (which are many):

Your `ul` has the `id='menu2'`, you were trying to select the `a` elements within the element with `id="menu"` (`$('#menu a')`). This, as you should expect, did not, and *could not*, work. Instead use the selector:

```
$('#menu2 a')
```

Your JavaScript was adding the class `makeVisible`, your CSS was expecting the class-name of `makeVisable`, again this could not work (or at least could not work if your CSS was attempting to style the class-name that your JavaScript was adding/removing); mind your spelling: JavaScript is case-sensitive *and* (very) *spelling* sensitive. It will not, cannot and really *should* not try and guess what you're trying to do.

Further, what's with the wall of `document.getElementById()...`? If you're using jQuery *use* jQuery; yes, the DOM is faster but, especially in a demo, make it easy for us to help you. Working out what that was doing (especially when `div11` to `div20` *don't event exist*) is irritating, and unnecessary. So, in the code demo I'm linking to (momentarily), I've replaced that with the jQuery:

```
$('#content div').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass('level1');
});
```

Anyway, the corrections I've fixed are listed above; and the updated demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WjRK2/70/

Oh, and as noted in the comments, if your demo uses jQuery please take the time to include jQuery in the demo you provide (it's an option in the `select` box to the top left corner of the page).

Comment: First off let me say sorry for the non-minimal code. This is my second time posting on this forum and my first time ever writing html.  The code, as you have seen, was created by taking bits and pieces from guides that I had found online, so that is probably why there are so many problems...  I like the changes that you have made, and thank you for finding my silly spelling mistakes, however it seems that the divs still do not appear once a color is clicked on the left hand side. How can I make those hidden divs appear?